# Flyway Migrations from JBOSS ESB

Tags: flyway

My team is trying to use Flyway to migrate our database during deployment of our JBOSS ESB packages.  We created a Migration MBean that calls flyway to initialize and migrate our database.

During deployment we get the following error:

**DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR**:
  Deployment "vfszip:/opt/jboss-soa-p.5.2.0/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/our-package.esb/
" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry db/migration not found in /opt/jboss-soa-p.5.2.0/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/our-package.esb

**Environment**: 
JBOSS 5.2.0
Flyway Core 2.0.3

```
Structure of ESB Package (our-package.esb)
```

`|lib
|db
  |migration
    |V1__Initial_structure.sql
    |V1_1__Populate_table.sql
|jboss-service.xml
|META-INF`

Our deployments will mainly consist of queues, topics and associated listeners.  We have multiple ESB packages to deploy across several environments.

**Update**
2013-02-18 12:33:11,700 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] (HDScanner) 
Error installing to Start: name=our.pack.age:service=DBMigrator state=Create mode=Manual 
requiredState=Installed
com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: 
Unable to scan for SQL migrations in location: db/migration
    at 
com.googlecode.flyway.core.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(SqlMigrationResolver.java:97)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.collectMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:219)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.doFindAvailableMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:157)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:127)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.info.MigrationInfoServiceImpl.refresh(MigrationInfoServiceImpl.java:86)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.info.MigrationInfoServiceImpl.(MigrationInfoServiceImpl.java:79)
    at 
com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway$4.execute(Flyway.java:1019)
    at 
com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway$4.execute(Flyway.java:1012)
    at 
com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1259)
    at 
com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.info(Flyway.java:1012)
    at 
our.pack.age.DBMigrator.migrate(DBMigrator.java:52)
    at 
our.pack.age.DBMigrator.start(DBMigrator.java:31)
    at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
...More

**Caused by**: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
JAR entry db/migration not found in /opt/jboss-soa-p.5.2.0/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/our-package.esb
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
    at 
sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:71)
    at 
com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.JarFileLocationScanner.getJarFromUrl(JarFileLocationScanner.java:55)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.JarFileLocationScanner.findResourceNames(JarFileLocationScanner.java:34)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner.findResourceNames(ClassPathScanner.java:156)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner.scanForResources(ClassPathScanner.java:58)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(SqlMigrationResolver.java:86)
    ... 68 more

**DBMigrator** is our custom MBean used to call Flyway to migrate our database.
We are using Flyway default configurations with the exception of setOutOfOrder(**true**).
Test SQL files were placed in src/main/resources/db/migration.

Comment: Could you post your Flyway config and the Flyway log output? Also could you try placing a file in the db/migration folder? Thx

Comment: @AxelFontaine Updated with requested information.  Files were in the db/migration during the run that generated the error.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using the latest version of either JDK 5,6 or 7 and that the db/migration is effectively present within the compiled archive (not just the source tree)? Thx

Comment: @AxelFontaine This issue has been resolved.  I create a new project and started from scratch and everything worked as desired.  There were a series of changes that needed to be reverted that were causing our errors.  Thank you for your assistance.